# Setting numeric values in new field based on length and branches in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, fields-attributes, qgis-processing, unique-value

I'd like to know how to set incremental numeric values in a new field of a layer, which has been obtained by "shortest path from point to layer", based on the length and the branches. I need to use QGIS for this operation, and I've tried to use the processing "add autoincremental field" that could be useful in this case.

1 is the value of the maximum length of the path and we can start to autoincrement in the branch which contains this one. After completing the routes of the first branch, we can go on to the second branch and so on.

I show you an image to explain the expected output:

[image]

Any suggestions? The processing "add autoincremental field" is the right way?